# System.Object being the base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

This question may be usual for many, i tried for an hour to understand the things but getting no proper explanation.

MSDN says, **System.Object is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.**

When C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, how can I inherit, say a Class A to Class B. ? Because all classes, already inherits from System.Object right?
Here I am talking about the normal inheritance.

```
Class A { --- }
Class B : A { --- }
```

Please, clear my doubts.
Thank you.

**Update:**

Again, My doubt is about, All classes inheriting from System.Object, then that would make Class B having Class A as well as System.Object. From my above example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct, C# only allows single inheritence. The System.Object class is inherited implicitly by your Class A. So Class B is-a A, which is-a System.Object. This is taken care of by the compiler so you don't need to explicitly say that `Class A : System.Object` (though you can if you want).

Comment: Okay I understood this with A is-a System.Object. But then if **all classes are having default inheritance to System.Object**, doesn't that make Class B having two inheritance, i.e, Class A and System.Object?

Comment: Nope, Class B inherits from Class A only. It inherits System.Object by virtue of it inheriting from A, and A inheriting System.Object. The System.Object inheritance is added by the compiler to the *top* of all inheritance hierarchies... only the top.

Comment: Okay, so the final conclusion I am getting is, Every class inherits from System.Object, but in case of Application level inheritance, only the top most class gets the System.Object as a base class?

Comment: Yep - that's it. The System.Object parent is added to all base classes in an inheritance hierarchy (even if the hierarchy only has one class in it).

Answer (score 7):

Very easy.
Ape inherits from animal, chimpanzee inherits from ape. Chimpanzee inherits from animal too, but not primarily, only through ape. 
In .NET, if class does not state its inheritance explicitly, the compiler adds IL code to inherit it from System.Object. If it does, it inherits System.Object through parent types.

Answer (score 5):

Look, you can only have one father. But your father also can have a father. Thus, you inherit some attributes from your grandfather. `Dog` class inherits from `Mammals`, which in turn inherits from `Animal` class, which in turn inherits from `LivingThing` class.

Comment: ... which in turn inherits from System.Object class :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance means that e.g. class A inherits from both class B and class C directly, like this:

```
class A : B, C
```

That **doesn't work** in C#. Your example means that you inherit from a class which itself inherits from another, like this:

```
class A : object
{
}

class B : A
{
}
```

That is possible in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a slight confusion with the meaning of 'multiple inheritance'?

Multiple inheritance is **not** when 'B inherits from A, and A inherits from O'.  That's just a simple inheritance hierarchy -- which is a feature of C++, Java and C#.

In the above case, we'd say that B inherits **directly** from A, and inherits **indirectly** from O.  B inherits the (non-private) members from A, and, indirectly, the (non-private) members of O.

C++ in addition supports true multiple inheritance, which can sometimes be called 'mix-in inheritance':    An example of multiple inheritance would be

```
 class A : public O {};
 class B : A, O {};
```

Here B inherits directly from O, and **also** inherits directly from A -- In this case **two copies** of O's members exist in B, and to access the members of B that come from O, you need to specify which of those copies you want:

e.g. `b.O::omember;` or `b.A::omember;`

With large C++ class frameworks, you can often get undesired copies of base classes in your derived classes when you use multiple inheritance.  To get round this, C++ provides **virtual inheritance**, which forces only one copy of the virtual base class to be inherited:   The following example should make this clear (or make it even more confusing!)

```
// Note, a struct in C++ is simply a class with everything public
struct O { int omember; };
struct A1 :  O {};
struct B1 :  O, A1 {};

struct A2 :  virtual O {};
struct B2 :  virtual O, A2 {};

B1 b1;
B2 b2;

// There are two 'omember's in b1
b1.omember; // Compiler error - ambiguous
b1.A1::omember = 1;
b1.O::omember = 2;

// There's only one 'omember' in b2, so all the following three lines
// all set the same member
b2.A2::omember = 1;
b2.O::omember = 2;
b2.omember = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `A` inherits from System.Object. Class `B` inherits from class `A`, which inherits from `System.Object`

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit two classes, but you can inherit a hierarchy of classes.

```
System.Object
    |
     \-- Class A {}
         |
          \-- Class B {}



public class ClassA
{
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
}

public class ClassC : ClassB
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance means inheriting from multiple classes into one class. Your example is valid, but you wouldn't be able to do the following:

Class B : A,C { --- }

A definition for multiple inheritance:

"Multiple inheritance is a feature of some object-oriented computer programming languages in which a class can inherit behaviors and features from more than one superclass."

Comment: I understood there can't be multiple inheritance in C#, but again, if all classes inherit from System.Object, how can Class B have both, i.e. Class A and System.Object (with respect to my example)?