# Inheriting class from Object

Tags: c#, .net, object

I've found this declaration in the old project code:

```
public class Protokol:Object
```

Does it make any sense to inherit class from object? I am not sure if it was made on purpose or just a dirty code.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268782/system-object-being-the-base-class

Comment: Sometimes auto generated code looks liek that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a class to derive from, then you automatically derive from object.

The code there is just being explicit. It's not *wrong* to explicitly derive from object, but it's not necessary to do so either as this is the default. Most people choose to omit the `: object` to keep the code clear.

Answer (score 1):

No - every class inherits from Object - you don't have to make it explicit but it don't hurt either - so up to you.