# Isn't C# or the underlying CLR really supporting multiple inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

This must be either discussed or I'm being extremely stupid. There are plenty of similar threads as to why C# doesnt have MI, I have gone thru most. But I'm curious to know if C# isn't already supporting it implicitly.

Since every type in .NET derive from `System.Object` I can write a class as

```
Person : object { }
```

Now if I have

```
Employee : Person { }
```

Isn't it really

```
Employee : object, Person { }
```

1) Isn't `Employee` class already inheriting from two classes?

All the problems of multiple inheritance exists here too right? Lets say I have this:

```
Person : object
{
    new public Type GetType()
    {
        return null;
    } 
}

Employee : object, Person 
{ 

}
```

2) Now if I call `Employee.GetType()` should it call `Person.GetType()` or `object.GetType()`? The confusion exists right. I feel isnt C# magically giving some sort of inheritance precedence for `object` class [as its already in many languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#Mitigation) in case of MI?

Comment: "A derives from B, B derives from C" is not what is (normally) meant by multiple inheritance.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I know that. My confusion was with the chaining of classes. I mean if Employee inherits Person, I didnt know Employee stopped directly deriving from object class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Object being the base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268782/system-object-being-the-base-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're misunderstanding inheritance.

`Employee` inherits `Person`, **only**.
`Person` inherits `Object`.

`Employee` inherits `Object` *indirectly*, through `Person`.
Because `Person` stands between `Employee` and `Object`, there are no MI issues.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks. So it seems if I declare only `Employee` it inherits from `object` and if I declare `Employee : Person`, it inherits via `Person` alone..

Answer (score 2):

When people discuss multiple inheritance they normally mean inheriting directly from two parent classes.

The normal resolution of an instance method call is to travel up the inheritance heirarchy and stop at the first definition of the method.

It is the ability to directly inherit from two parent classes that introduces the [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem), which is a primary reason many people believe multiple inheritance is a bad idea.  With multiple parents, something required as part of the interface from high above can be overridden differently in the two parent classes, and there's no clear choice for which to use.

Different languages deal with this in different ways, and C# and Java indeed both deal with it by simply not allowing multiple inheritance,